# How to store values in list based on another list and tuple

Tags: python

I have a list `see = []`,where I need to insert symbols `(` , `.` , `)`
based on list `unpaired =[1,3]` and tuple list `paired=[(2,4)]+ .

Hence,for each value in list unpaired and tuple paired,I need to insert the characters in `see`.

For example,for value 1,3, in unpaired,I store '.' in 1st and 3rd position in list see.Similarly for 2,4 values in tuple paired,I store '(' and ')' at 2nd and 4th position respectively in list see.My end result should come something like this `see=[.,(,.,)]`

How can I proceed with it?

Comment: The thing you want is kind of weird. What are the use case of it? May be we could suggest you a different approach.

Comment: show us an example please, this is a confusing mess

Comment: @AhsanulHaque  Okk..I am working on traceback for dynamic programming algorithm for rna folding.

Comment: @DanielSanchez I have edited my query a bit.It is helpful ? or else,I will modify.

Comment: @SayaneShome, It's ok now, ill think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary, where the keys are the indices stored in `paired` and `unpaired`. This helps you to set up your output data, but -- unlike using a list -- you can store a value at an index when the other indices are not present yet.

```
for element in unpaired:
    yourDict[element] = '.'

for element in paired:
    yourDict[element[0]] = '('
    yourDict[element[1]] = ')'
```

now you can get the result by soring your dict keys (`sorted(yourDict)`) and calling `list(yourDict.values())`:

for example

```
unpaired = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
paired = [(2,4), (6,9)]

print(list(yourDict.values()))
```

prints

```
['.', '(', '.', ')', '.', '(', '.', '.' , ')']
```

Comment: if I have more than 2 elements in paired ? How to assign it ?

For example if paired has [(0, 14), (1, 12), (3, 10), (4, 9)]

Comment: something like `[firstTuple, secondTuple, ...]`: `paired = [(2,4), [6,9]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to map the value with the symbol, and then loop through your lists, like this:

```
>>> unpaired = [1,3]
>>> paired = [(2,4)]
>>> map_of_symbols = {1: '.', 2: '(', 3: '.', 4: ')'}
>>> values = sorted(unpaired+[i for x in paired for i in x])
>>> seen = [map_of_symbols[i] for i in values]
>>> seen
['.', '(', '.', ')']
```